# How bind current date on Kendo Angular date picker

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

Hi I am trying to use kendo date picker for angular. Everything works fine but on page load I want to bind current date like **4 August 2021** to display automatically. I tried different ways to do that but nothing works .

Here is my markup for the date picker,

```
<kendo-datepicker id="fromDate" [(ngModel)]="fromDate"
  class="m-2 col-md-12 col-xl-12 col-lg-12"  format="dd MMMM yyyy">
</kendo-datepicker>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So,Finally I Found a solution . On ngOnInit I added this piece of code

```
this.fromDate = new Date();
```

[image]

And found my desired output

Comment: Not sure if you know why this works, but you have a two-way binding on the component's `ngModel` directive. Presumably you declared your variable like such: `public fromDate: Date` without ever giving it a default value. By handling the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook and giving the variable a default value, the control gets updated accordingly.